# Call jQuery from javascript console when using JSFiddle

Tags: jquery, debugging, console, bind

It's typical in my debug and creation process to fire off a few jQuery commands from the javascript console (firebug in firefox or chrome's built-in) just for inspection and testing purposes. I've noticed that I'm unable to interact with any elements in the page on JSFiddle using the jQuery() call, and that $() doesn't behave normally either (I'm guessing it's bound to mootools or X other framework?) Looking at the list of scripts used on the page tells me that the jQuery library is loaded.

Any ideas on how I can call something as simple as jQuery("body").toggle("slow"); from the firebug or chrome javascript console? Any simple way to find out jQuery's binding?

not that it's necessary, but here is a jsfiddle using jQuery for your testing purposes. http://jsfiddle.net/HHecw/

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the console directly in the jsFiddle frame.
jsFiddle uses MooTools, not jQuery.

To interact with your page from the console, you need to open the "result" frame directly, from http://fiddle.jshell.net/HHecw/show/light/

Comment: While this is definitely helpful and I am very appreciative, is it possible to call jQuery from the jsFiddle frame screen? Is jQuery simply bound to another constructor? I understand that JSFiddle uses mootools, but I can clearly see that jQuery is has been loaded from the list of scripts loaded in firebug. Any ideas??

Thanks again!

Comment: @Jason: Firebug's Scripts tag show scripts from all frames in the page.  However, the console only interacts with the root frame.