# how to check values on console bind function on console?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please tell me how the developer check many things on console, while writing some code on console and press enter?

I also start doing but fail to achieve things.

First I take button on fiddle

```
<button id="test">test</button>
```

.[image]

```
write these instruction on console.
$('#test')
null
$('#test').click(function(){)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
$('#test').click(function(){alert('---')})
TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. jquery-1.9.1.js:3345
$('#test').click(function(){alert('---')})
TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mitch already mentioned, jQuery isn't loaded on jsFiddle. So, you won't be able to use jQuery in the Developer tools.

The other issue you face is that your output window is contained in an iFrame. Not only that, it's a different domain which brings in security concerns. EVEN if jQuery WAS loaded, if you tried to access `$('#test')`, you would see an error like this:

```
SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 
'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://jsfiddle.net" from
accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

So, how do we address this? When you open up Developer Tools, you'll want to do the following:

1) In Developer Tools, type the following: `document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src`

That will return the URL (something like: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/MYA32/show/") to your fiddle page. If you don't see one, it means you haven't saved your fiddle.

2) Open that URL in a new window.

Here's a jsfiddle with jQuery included. You should now be able to use jQuery! http://fiddle.jshell.net/MYA32/show/

BTW, you may notice that the iFrame URL is the same format for all (just the stuff between fiddle.jshell.net and show change. That should help you quickly open outputs in the future.

Comment: Please look on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725795/how-to-make-collapsible-list-dynamically?noredirect=1#comment34635313_22725795

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387661/call-jquery-from-javascript-console-when-using-jsfiddle) answer, JSFiddle uses MooTools, not JQuery, which can be confirmed by checking the sources loaded in by the website.  This means your $ function calls are not calling the jquery functions you're expecting, and thus why the results aren't what you're hoping for.

Comment: but some developer can check on console of any site like stack overflow

Comment: can you please tell me how I open my result

Comment: Jquery is not universally defined like Javascript, so the functions must be defined by the page loading the plugin. Without the plugin, the functions are never defined and thus any calls to them will result in errors.  

If you want to open your result frame, you can save the fiddle and open it at jsfiddle.net/#yourfiddleid#/show/light/

Comment: thanks got it..can you look this question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725795/how-to-make-collapsible-list-dynamically?noredirect=1#comment34635313_22725795

Comment: I think this achieve by jquery ui or jquery mobile